# How to encrypt data using SSL in Android?

Tags: android, ssl

In my app, I need to create a registration form with username and password combination.But it needs to go to the server encrypted.Could you please let me know if I can use SSL for that and if yes, how to use it?

Thank you.

Comment: Is your serve running on https?